# Chrome URL bar makes 100vh scrollable

Tags: css, mobile

I have a page on my website, that cannot be scrollable. It looks all right on desktop devices, it looks good on mobile when the URL bar is hidden, but when it is visible the page becomes scrollable.

[image]

I tried code below but without success.

```
height: calc(100vh - 72px - env(viewport-nav-resize));
```

I want the textearea to be always 100% visible and page not to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a `height` use `position: absolute` with `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` set to 0 ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/absolute-container-dzhqo?fontsize=14) - click full screen button):

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```